# Vim yank and paste non-standard characters

Tags: vim

I have a document with a non-standard encoding.  Some of them aren't valid UTF-8, etc.  However, a lot of the starts/ends of sections etc still line up, so I would still like to do some basic things in vim with this document.  One of those things is to copy and paste.  However this seems to fail when my document isn't in a standard encoding.

I can't provide my original document, but one can easily experiment with this with other arbitrary files.  For example, if you open a .jpg file in vim, and then (y)ank all of it and (P)aste it into a new file, and save that file as a .jpg, it won't open.  Somewhere in the yank-paste pipeline stuff got lost.  What is going on with my vim clipboard, and is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Vim's way of dealing with multiple encodings in a same buffer is simply to convert everything to one single encoding. It may work if the original encoding and the new one "match" but, given the number of encodings in the wild, it is very likely to fail most of the time. I'm afraid this is something that won't be fixable in Vim with Vim.